# Kafka Spark Streaming Exception thrown in awaitResult

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am trying to integrate Kafka with Apache Spark Streaming, Here is code -

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.TaskContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.VoidFunction;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Duration;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaInputDStream;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.ConsumerStrategies;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.HasOffsetRanges;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaUtils;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.LocationStrategies;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.OffsetRange;

public class SampleSparkStraming {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //SparkContext context = new 
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SampleAPP").setMaster("spark://localhost:4040").set("spark.ui.port","4040");
    //SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SampleAPP").setMaster("local[*]");
    JavaStreamingContext ssc = new JavaStreamingContext(conf, new Duration(500000));

    Map<String, Object> kafkaParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    kafkaParams.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
    kafkaParams.put("key.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class);
    kafkaParams.put("value.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class);
    kafkaParams.put("group.id", "use_a_separate_group_id_for_each_stream");
    kafkaParams.put("auto.offset.reset", "latest");
    kafkaParams.put("enable.auto.commit", false);

    Collection<String> topics = Arrays.asList("TEST-Kafka");

    final JavaInputDStream<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> stream =
              KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(
                ssc,
                LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent(),
                ConsumerStrategies.<String, String>Subscribe(topics, kafkaParams)
              );

    stream.foreachRDD(new VoidFunction<JavaRDD<ConsumerRecord<String, String>>>() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public void call(JavaRDD<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> rdd) {

            final OffsetRange[] offsetRanges = ((HasOffsetRanges) rdd.rdd()).offsetRanges();
            rdd.foreachPartition(new VoidFunction<Iterator<ConsumerRecord<String, String>>>() {
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                public void call(Iterator<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> consumerRecords) {
                    OffsetRange o = offsetRanges[TaskContext.get().partitionId()];
                    System.out.println(o.topic() + " " + o.partition() + " " + o.fromOffset() + " " + o.untilOffset());
                }
            });
        }
    });
    //stream.print();
}
}
```

`pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Versions - 
`kafka_2.10-0.10.2.0`
`spark-2.1.0`
`OS - Windows 7`

When i try with cmd consumer from Kafka, messages are getting consumed, but not working with other Program .. getting following exception -

```
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
17/04/10 17:07:32 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 2.1.0
17/04/10 17:07:33 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
17/04/10 17:07:33 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: xxxxx
17/04/10 17:07:33 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: xxxxxx
17/04/10 17:07:33 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
17/04/10 17:07:33 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
17/04/10 17:07:33 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(xxxxx); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(xxxxx); groups with modify permissions: Set()
17/04/10 17:07:33 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 55878.
17/04/10 17:07:33 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
17/04/10 17:07:33 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
17/04/10 17:07:33 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Using org.apache.spark.storage.DefaultTopologyMapper for getting topology information
17/04/10 17:07:33 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: BlockManagerMasterEndpoint up
17/04/10 17:07:33 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at C:\Users\xxxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\blockmgr-38e935a6-96c1-4942-a88f-6b7c8677fba7
17/04/10 17:07:33 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 349.2 MB
17/04/10 17:07:33 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
17/04/10 17:07:33 WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4040. Attempting port 4041.
17/04/10 17:07:33 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4041.
17/04/10 17:07:33 INFO SparkUI: Bound SparkUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://10.10.25.26:4041
17/04/10 17:07:33 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Connecting to master spark://localhost:4040...
17/04/10 17:07:33 INFO TransportClientFactory: Successfully created connection to localhost/127.0.0.1:4040 after 18 ms (0 ms spent in bootstraps)
17/04/10 17:07:33 ERROR TransportResponseHandler: Still have 1 requests outstanding when connection from localhost/127.0.0.1:4040 is closed
17/04/10 17:07:33 WARN StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Failed to connect to master localhost:4040
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult
at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:77)
at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:36)
at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:59)
at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:59)
at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.apply(PartialFunction.scala:167)
at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:83)
at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRefByURI(RpcEnv.scala:100)
at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRef(RpcEnv.scala:108)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.client.StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint$$anonfun$tryRegisterAllMasters$1$$anon$1.run(StandaloneAppClient.scala:106)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connection from localhost/127.0.0.1:4040 closed
at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportResponseHandler.channelInactive(TransportResponseHandler.java:128)
at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelInactive(TransportChannelHandler.java:109)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:251)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:237)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:230)
at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelInactive(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:75)
at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelInactive(IdleStateHandler.java:257)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:251)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:237)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:230)
at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelInactive(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:75)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:251)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:237)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:230)
at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelInactive(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:75)
at org.apache.spark.network.util.TransportFrameDecoder.channelInactive(TransportFrameDecoder.java:182)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:251)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:237)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:230)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1289)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:251)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:237)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:893)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$7.run(AbstractChannel.java:691)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:408)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:455)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:140)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
... 1 more
```

And on Spark Window, getting following error -

```
17/04/10 17:07:33 WARN HttpParser: Illegal character 0x0 in state=START for buffer HeapByteBuffer@73f2273b[p=1,l=1292,c=16384,r=1291]={\x00<<<\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\x0c\x03_>\xF5s.bKM\x00...Ft\x00\x0b10.10.25.26>>>\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00...\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00}
17/04/10 17:07:33 WARN HttpParser: badMessage: 400 Illegal character 0x0 for HttpChannelOverHttp@1a099881{r=0,c=false,a=IDLE,uri=}
```

There are similar question and answer was related to version conflicts, but i am unable to detect the issue.

Comment: Are you sure, you are using correct master URL in code?

Comment: And you're using Scala 2.10?

Comment: @Kaushal , Yes, When i hit url "http://localhost:4040", It's showing Spark UI.

Comment: The UI that it is showing, is master UI or your application UI?

Comment: @Kaushal I am new to These technologies.. So not Sure, but when i started the Spark, This is what printed - `Spark context Web UI available at http://10.10.25.26:4040Spark context available as 'sc' (master = local[*], app id = local-1491819268616).
Spark session available as 'spark'.
Welcome to  Spark   version 2.1.0
Using Scala version 2.11.8 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_66)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.`

Comment: **.setMaster("local[*]")** change your code with this and try.

Comment: @Kaushal, not getting any error by application getting terminated with without any output.

Comment: Reason is that, you are not starting your StreamContext.

Comment: @Kaushal, Yes this is working. Thanks. I haven't changed anything as suggested, only **.setMaster("local[*]")** & added 2 line **ssc.start();** **ssc.awaitTermination(); **

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are running spark application in standalone mode then you need have cluster up first and use that url in your application, if not you can simply use local[*] mode to run your spark application.

And as per your code you also need to start your streamingcontext to get the data from kafka.

Comment: But Just for curiosity, What will be the value in case of cluster environment?

Comment: Once your cluster is up you can see your default cluster UI with **http://localhost:8080** Url. And in top-left corner section you can see you master url. Use that Url in your application to connect with spark cluser. 
[![Spark Master UI][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7eF6X.png

Comment: i started with cluster mode and replaced URL as suggested but getting error `ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaRDDPartition` running eclipse. Any Idea. Jar is in classpath

Comment: Ask this as a separate question and provide detailed description, so it can help others.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your URIs are correct, Apache Spark does not support Scala 2.12 right now. Besides, the "2.10" inside `kafka_2.10-0.10.2.0` means that is supposed to be deployed with Scala 2.10 anyway.

So at the very least, use Scala 2.11.8, and then link this Kafka connector as shown in the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-0-8-integration.html):

```
groupId = org.apache.spark
artifactId = spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11
version = 2.1.0
```

Comment: Sorry for incorrect information, in Spark log it is showing as `Using Scala version 2.11.8`

Comment: That's fine, but your connector is still mismatched.